# Is there any website for provide APIs for making transaction to different blockchain such as Ethereum, Litecoin, BTC, Neo etc

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, bitcoin

I want build a wallet which manages multiple coins and I'm looking for a website which provides APIs for transacting to different blockchains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short No, because what what you're essentially asking for is a crypto exchange mechanism.

What you're probably looking for is an API to create wallet for multiple coins of a variety of blockchain and have your backend to instantiate these wallets and make pair exchanges. However i do not see why your product would be any different from the API provider.